# window function is not working as expected

Tags: r, time-series

I have a monthly time series - monthlyTs:

```
monthlyTs <- ts(all.xts , frequency = 12, start=decimal_date(ymd("2012-01-29")))
head(index(monthlyTs))
```

> [1](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2959b9b7716b9c8899145a4bfa5d1160/christmas.csv) "2012-01-29 00:00:00 UTC" "2012-02-26 01:22:47 UTC" "2012-03-25
>   02:45:35 UTC" "2012-04-29 04:29:04 UTC"
>       [5] "2012-05-27 05:51:52 UTC" "2012-06-24 07:14:39 UTC"

I want to apply a time windows that starts from 2013:

```
head(window(monthly, start = 2013))
```

> 2012-01-29 00:00:00    2
>
> 2012-02-26 01:22:47    8 2012-03-25 02:45:35    6 2012-04-29 04:29:04 
>   5 2012-05-27 05:51:52    4 2012-06-24 07:14:39    4

So looks like window function is not filtering as expected. What is wrong?

---

Fully reproducible example as requested:

[christmas.csv - tiny CSV file (google trends for 'Christmas' request)](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2959b9b7716b9c8899145a4bfa5d1160/christmas.csv)

```
#Reading data from the csv. Format - [week start date], [views per week]
data = read.csv('christmas.csv',  sep=",", header = FALSE, skip = 3,col.names = c("Week","Views"))[[2]]

# creating time series
myTs <- ts(data[[2]], freq=365.25/7, start=decimal_date(ymd("2012-01-29")))

#converting from weekly to month time series
all.xts <- xts(myTs, date_decimal(index(myTs)))
monthlyTs <- ts(all.xts , frequency = 12, start=decimal_date(ymd("2012-01-29")))

head(window(monthlyTs, start = 2013))
```

> 2012-01-29 00:00:00 2
>
> 2012-02-26 01:22:47 8 2012-03-25 02:45:35 6 2012-04-29 04:29:04 5
>   2012-05-27 05:51:52 4 2012-06-24 07:14:39 4

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example ?

Comment: @EtienneKintzler added

Comment: Please edit your second line. You use `data[[2]]`. It should be `data`. Also next time instead of providing a link to download the dataset you should copy paste the output of `dput` called on your object `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems :

1. the object `all.xts` is a weekly and not a monthly time
2. The value your pass for the argument frequency is not correct

For the second point, try to change the value you pass for the argument `start` in your call of the function `ts` with

```
c(lubridate::year("2012-01-29"), lubridate::month("2012-01-29"))
```

and change the frequency to value 12. i.e use the line :

```
ts(all.xts , frequency = 12, start = c(lubridate::year("2012-01-29"), lubridate::month("2012-01-29")) )
```

Using the output from `dput`, your code rewrite as follow :

```
data <- c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 16L, 22L, 33L, 42L, 
          45L, 55L, 64L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
          12L, 16L, 21L, 27L, 43L, 47L, 56L, 79L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
          3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 43L, 47L, 53L, 
          87L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 
          17L, 20L, 27L, 44L, 50L, 54L, 100L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
          3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 29L, 43L, 48L, 53L, 80L, 
          46L, 8L, 3L, 2L)

myTs <- ts(data, freq=365.25/7, start=decimal_date(ymd("2012-01-29")))
all.xts <- xts::xts(myTs, date_decimal(index(myTs)))
monthlyTs <- ts(all.xts , frequency = 12, start = c(lubridate::year("2012-01-29"), lubridate::month("2012-01-29")) )
window(monthlyTs, start= c(2013))
```

The last line will print :

```
> window(monthlyTs, start= c(2013))
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2013   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2014   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   4
2015   5   5   6   8  11  16  22  33  42  45  55  64
2016   8   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1
2017   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2018   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2
2019   3   3   3   4   4   5   6   8  12  16  21  27
2020  43  47  56  79  10   5   2   2   2   1   1   1
2021   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2022   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2
2023   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   5   5   6   8
2024  12  17  21  27  43  47  53  87  12   5   2   2
2025   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2026   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2027   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   4
2028   5   6   6   8  13  17  20  27  44  50  54 100
2029  15   6   3   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2030   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2031   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
2032   3   3   3   4   5   5   6   8  11  16  21  29
2033  43  48  53  80  46   8   3   2
```